# Database normalization vs wildcard queries

Tags: database, database-design

I've been wondering if normalization is needed. My primary concern is not the readability and ease of use of these tables but speed. Take for example a car table. Assume this car table has upwards of 10,000 records.

**My question is: is the time penalty of doing many joins worth the better design of a database system? and how what is the difference between doing '%%' queries vs joins**

### Cars

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|CarID  |Car_Name   |         Car_Features                   |
------------------------------------------------------------- 
|F31344 | Corolla   | Sedan - Sun Roof Power Lock Manual 4WD |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

and doing queries like :

> 1. Select Car_ID,Car_Name,Car_Features From Cars Where Car_Features like '%4WD'%;
> 2. Select Car_Name from Cars where Car_Features like '%Manual Sun Roof%';

Duration/Fetch time is relatively fast.

**Vs the normalized approach.**

Cars

```
------------------------------------------
|Car_ID | Car_Name |Transmission|Features|
------------------------------------------
|F31344 | Corolla  | M4WD       | EX1    |
------------------------------------------
```

Transmission

```
---------------------------------
|ID           | Drive | Manual  |
--------------------------------
|M4WD         | 4WD   |   1     |
--------------------------------


Features
---------------------------------
|Features | Sun_Roof | Power_lock|
---------------------------------
|EX1      | 1         |     0    |
---------------------------------
```

Now I have to write joins to accomplish the same thing. As well as introducing two new tables, and two look-up columns in my original table.

```
> 1.Select Car_ID,Car_Name,Drive From Cars inner join Transmission
> ON Cars.Transmission = Transmission.ID
> Where Drive = '4WD';
```

Comment: It totally depends on a thousand things there wouldn't be enough time to share here. Best answer I can give is an opinion: start normalized and denormalize as needed.

Comment: Normalization is used to reduce data redundancy and in some case data is denormalised to improved performance. But keeping in mind your business requirements you can settle somewhere in the middle without   to much compromise on either ends.

Comment: Why is this tagged for both MySQL and SQL Server?  Which database are you using?

Comment: 10k rows is tiny. Nevertheless, the expression `like '%4WD'%` isn't sargable. (It can't use an index.) Also note that you've considered (or misconsidered) readability, ease of use, and speed, but you haven't considered data integrity.

Comment: I second what @MikeSherrill'Catcall' said. Join will actually be faster than full table scan (that you have now). May not be too important for only 10000 rows, but could mean a difference between milliseconds and minutes (or more) on larger tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization is not about performance, although in most cases improved performance is a side effect of properly normalized database. It mostly about **integrity and consistency** of your data.

In denormalized approach you won't be able to normally maintain (e.g. consistently add new or update existing features to(of) all cars records) and query your data (when you start to mix and match car features). And your second query is a perfect illustration to that

```sql
Select Car_Name from Cars where Car_Features like '%Manual Sun Roof%';
```

This query **won't return you anything**.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fa0e/2)** demo

Recommended reading:

- [SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557) by @BillKarwin

Comment: sorry i meant `Select Car_Name from Cars where Car_Features like '%Manual%' OR Features like '%Sun Roof%' ;`

Comment: Imagine that "Sun Roof" is a mistake. Write a query to remove "Sun Roof" from the features.

Comment: What if a feature misspelled in one record or two or `roof` goes before `sun`? Now what if a feature has a similar compound name - something like `sun glass`? How do you tell one from the other??? It's a data maintenance nightmare. Now try to build any real world report on top this renormalized data...

Comment: The huge drawback of a denormalized approach - you can't formulate a query that will do a simple dynamic aggregation for you like *Give me the number of cars available for **each color** that we have in stock*. Try to write a query to answer this simple question

Comment: @peterm i see your point maintenance would indeed be a nightmare, guess i'll go with the normalized approach

Comment: @Edward Great! Good luck :) Meanwhile if you feel like the answer was helpful please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** it.